# show distinct item in a dropdownlistfor in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using the following code to bind my dropdownlist.
the foliodividentlist can have multiple values. I only want to bind unique values but not able to do so
where am i wrong please help.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuyMoreList[i].FolioNo,
new SelectList(Model.BuyMoreList[i].FolioDividendList.Select(x =>
    new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.FolioNo.ToString(),
        Text = x.FolioNo
    }).Distinct(), "Value", "Text")
```

Comment: Where do you get the `i` in BuyMoreList[i]?

Comment: What is your issue? Are you not getting expected result, or are you getting exception? Please add your complete code where you are using `i`, and also add your model code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuyMoreList[i].FolioNo,
new SelectList(Model.BuyMoreList[i].FolioDividendList.GroupBy(x => x.FolioNo)
                    .Select(x =>
                       {
                           var firstSet = x.First();
                           return new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = firstSet.FolioNo.ToString(),
                               Text = firstSet.FolioNo
                           };
                        }
               ),"Value", "Text")
```